# How to open a xcode framework file in telerik hybrid coredova application using telerik appbuilder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, hybrid-mobile-app, telerik-appbuilder

I want to open or call my iOS SDK framework file in the telerick hybrid coredova application. Share if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to open a framework directly in any of the AppBuilder clients. However, you can use a custom (or third-party) iOS framework in your app by creating a Cordova plugin. To do so, you would require knowledge in native iOS development. [This article](http://www.codepool.biz/cordova-plugin-custom-ios-framework.html) contains additional information on the subject.